# How can I implement an onClickListener on top of OnSwipeListener for GridView?

Tags: java, android, gridview, onclicklistener

I have a GridView that I use to display months and I want to be able to click on each item (day) and open a new activity as well as changing the month when swiped up/down for previous/next month.
How can I implement both of them at the same time?

I saw another problem similar to mine, but that couldn't help my case either.

When using setOnTouchListener(OnSwipeListener) I managed to detect the actions when swiping perfectly, but then I couldn't make the gridview clickable with any onTouchListener.

The code for onSwipe action

```
        gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeListener(this) {
            public void onSwipeTop() {
                Toast.makeText(CalendarActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                Toast.makeText(CalendarActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                Toast.makeText(CalendarActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onSwipeBottom() {
                Toast.makeText(CalendarActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.performClick();  // If we create a custom gridview using public boolean performClick it is going to work. For now it doesnt.
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
```

The code for onClick action

```
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(CalendarActivity.this, "Clicked: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            }
        });
```

The result from using both of those is that I get the correct results for the onSwipe methods (left/right/up/down) but when clicking each item in the GridView it clicks the first day of each Week(Monday) and after a while it crashes.

If there is any other way to add a onSwipeListener to a basic GridView I would also attempt to use it.

The setOnTouchListener for OnSwipe is getting an error does not override performClick anyways, so there is probably a better way to do it.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem once with scrollview and things i touched inside it, there are kind of intereferences. Maybe you can try to put gridView inside a container view and put the listeners separately. One in the container and one in the gridView